# WordPress Blog Parse Errors

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know why, but all of a sudden my blog is down with lots of parse errors. I suppose maybe it was because an automatic version update of the WordPress blog, but I am not sure yet.

After fixing the first error, now there is another one, which WordPress says to be on the following snippet of code:

```
$wpdb->field_types = array( 'post_author' => '%d', 'post_parent' => '%d', 'menu_order' => '%d', 'term_id' => '%derm_group' => '%d', 'term_taxonomy_id' => '%d',
    'parent' => '%d', 'count' => '%d','object_id' => '%d', 'term_order' => '%d', 'ID' => '%d', 'comment_ID' => '%d', 'comment_post_ID' => '%d', 'comment_parent' => '%d',
    'user_id' => '%d', 'link_id' => '%d', 'link_owner' => '%d', 'link_rating' => '%d', 'option_id' => '%d', 'blog_id' => '%d', 'meta_id' => '%d', 'post_id' => '%d',
    'user_status' => '%d', 'umeta_id' => '%d', 'comment_karma' => '%d', 'comment_count' => '%d',
    // multisite:
    'active' => '%d', 'cat_id' => '%d', 'deleted' => '%d', 'lang_id' => '%d', 'mature' => '%d', 'public' => '%d', 'site_id' => '%d', 'spam' => '%d',
);
```

What is it wrong with this code?

Comment: Outside of the extra comma at the end of the list, the only thing I see wrong is you didn't post the error.  The server was nice enough to show you, share the kindness. ;)

Comment: A code prettifier would make the error obvious.

Comment: I removed the comma, but it still insists to say there is a parse error: PHP Parse error:  parse error, expecting `')'' in load.php on line 356

Comment: I just updated my first code block to reflect Gergo's latest superb catch.  I highly recommend applying that adjustment *and* upvoting him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** This answer is corrected only b/c I cannot delete it as the accepted answer, but credit properly belongs to Gergo.

Your response to my comment requesting details clarifies the answer.  On the second-to-last line of your code, it ends with a comma.  That comma is before the close of the array, so should not be there.  Remove it and problem solved.

The error message is saying, "Yo, there's something other than a right parenthesis where I am looking, figure out what needs to go there, dude."  That "something" is the comma.

Applying this fix *and* Gergo's, the code becomes:

```
$wpdb->field_types = array( 'post_author' => '%d', 'post_parent' => '%d', 'menu_order' => '%d', 'term_id' => '%d', 'term_group' => '%d', 'term_taxonomy_id' => '%d',
        'parent' => '%d', 'count' => '%d','object_id' => '%d', 'term_order' => '%d', 'ID' => '%d', 'comment_ID' => '%d', 'comment_post_ID' => '%d', 'comment_parent' => '%d',
        'user_id' => '%d', 'link_id' => '%d', 'link_owner' => '%d', 'link_rating' => '%d', 'option_id' => '%d', 'blog_id' => '%d', 'meta_id' => '%d', 'post_id' => '%d',
        'user_status' => '%d', 'umeta_id' => '%d', 'comment_karma' => '%d', 'comment_count' => '%d',
        // multisite:
        'active' => '%d', 'cat_id' => '%d', 'deleted' => '%d', 'lang_id' => '%d', 'mature' => '%d', 'public' => '%d', 'site_id' => '%d', 'spam' => '%d'
    );
```

or

```
$wpdb->field_types = array( 'post_author' => '%d', 'post_parent' => '%d', 'menu_order' => '%d', 'term_id' => '%d', 'derm_group' => '%d', 'term_taxonomy_id' => '%d',
        'parent' => '%d', 'count' => '%d','object_id' => '%d', 'term_order' => '%d', 'ID' => '%d', 'comment_ID' => '%d', 'comment_post_ID' => '%d', 'comment_parent' => '%d',
        'user_id' => '%d', 'link_id' => '%d', 'link_owner' => '%d', 'link_rating' => '%d', 'option_id' => '%d', 'blog_id' => '%d', 'meta_id' => '%d', 'post_id' => '%d',
        'user_status' => '%d', 'umeta_id' => '%d', 'comment_karma' => '%d', 'comment_count' => '%d',
        // multisite:
        'active' => '%d', 'cat_id' => '%d', 'deleted' => '%d', 'lang_id' => '%d', 'mature' => '%d', 'public' => '%d', 'site_id' => '%d', 'spam' => '%d'
    );
```

The answer depends on the underlying structure, so test the first, then the second.

Comment: `array('a', 'b', );` is valid. From the manual: "The comma after the last array element is optional and can be omitted.".

Comment: @GergoErdosi Thanks.  Guess not having it is habit and what led me to think the error message was for that.

Comment: Thanks! The first one did the trick!

Comment: I thought it might.  Somehow they got messed up on the `%d`, so I guessed at removing both characters.

Comment: But now there is an error in another line of code! I thought I had disabled this auto-update feature of WordPress, but it looks like I didn't, and now will have a nightmare trying to fix all these errors.

Comment: Or revert on a backup if you've got one.  Also, I highly recommend upvoting Gergo's answer... an upvote means it was useful and his contribution was fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo in the beginning of the array. This is not a valid syntax:

```
'term_id' => '%derm_group' => '%d'
```

You should change it to:

```
'term_id' => '%d', 'term_group' => '%d'
```

Comment: Stellar catch.  After addressing the current error, what you found would be the next.  He got 2 answers for 1 question!

Comment: Where is the error? Sorry, I am not a PHP programmer, but my blog is written in PHP, so I only work with PHP in times like this. What I mean is: could you give me a little more information about what you say the error to be, please? Thanks

Comment: He did.  Look for the first code block and change those characters to what's in the second code block... that fixes an error you're not seeing yet.  So, go to my answer which is about the error you are currently seeing and ditch that last comma, too.

Comment: The error is on the first line. `'a' => 'b' => 'c'` is not a valid syntax. Associative arrays have key-value pairs, so only `'a' => 'b'` is valid.

Comment: Again, phenomenal catch!  I bet you're right with the `term_group`. Wish I could upvote you twice!